# UWP, VPN authentication with app container certificates

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, vpn

I'm building a UWP app that programmatically creates a Windows built-in VPN profile `VpnNativeProfile`, 
then attempts to connect to the remote server via the VPN management agent `VpnManagementAgent.ConnectProfileAsync(IVpnProfile)` method.

The profile is set up to use a certificate based authentication, via the EAP authentication method.

Is there a way of programmatically setting the certificate while connecting the profile, or instructing the VPN plugin to use the certificate stored in the same app container? 
The VPN agent doesn't seem to be able to find the client certificate unless I import it in the machine shared user storage `Certificates - Current User\Personal\Certificates`.
Is there a way to expose the certificate to the VPN profile without installing it outside of the app sandbox?

Thank you!